# How to generate HMAC-SHA1 in C#?

Tags: c#, java, php, ruby, hmac

I am trying to make use of a REST API using C#. The API creator has provided sample libraries in PHP, Ruby and Java. I am getting hung up on one part of it where I need to generate an [`HMAC`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC).

Here's how it is done in the sample libraries they have provided.

**PHP**

```
hash_hmac('sha1', $signatureString, $secretKey, false);
```

**Ruby**

```
digest = OpenSSL::Digest::Digest.new('sha1')
return OpenSSL::HMAC.hexdigest(digest, secretKey, signatureString)
```

**Java**

```
SecretKeySpec signingKey = new SecretKeySpec(secretKey.getBytes(), HMAC_SHA1_ALGORITHM);

Mac mac = null;
mac = Mac.getInstance(HMAC_SHA1_ALGORITHM);
mac.init(signingKey);

byte[] bytes = mac.doFinal(signatureString.getBytes());

String form = "";
for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++)
{
    String str = Integer.toHexString(((int)bytes[i]) & 0xff);
    if (str.length() == 1)
    {
        str = "0" + str;
    }

    form = form + str;
}
return form;
```

**Here's my attempt in C#. <strike>It is not working.</strike> UPDATE:** The C# example below works just fine. I found out that the real problem was due to some cross-platform differences in newline characters in my `signatureString`.

```
var enc = Encoding.ASCII;
HMACSHA1 hmac = new HMACSHA1(enc.GetBytes(secretKey));
hmac.Initialize();

byte[] buffer = enc.GetBytes(signatureString);
return BitConverter.ToString(hmac.ComputeHash(buffer)).Replace("-", "").ToLower();
```

Comment: Turns out my C# code works just fine. The real problem was due to some cross-platform differences in newline characters in my the `signatureString`. I will flag this question for deletion.

Comment: Instead of deleting the question, post your code as an answer and accept it. This question is very useful who seek to do the same thing.

Comment: I added a further update on the text "The API responds..."  to avoid potential misunderstandings

Answer (score 42):

an extension to [Vimvq1987's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6067751/how-to-generate-hmac-sha1-in-c/6067882#6067882):

`return hashValue.ToString();` doesn't produce the output you want/need. You have to convert the bytes in the array `hashValue` to their hex-string representation.
Can be as simple as `return BitConverter.toString(hashValue);` (prints upper-case letters A-F) or if you like it a bit more complex:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        public static string Encode(string input, byte[] key)
        {
            HMACSHA1 myhmacsha1 = new HMACSHA1(key);
            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input);
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
            return myhmacsha1.ComputeHash(stream).Aggregate("", (s, e) => s + String.Format("{0:x2}",e), s => s );
        }


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            byte[] key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");
            string input = "";
            foreach (string s in new string[] { "Marry", " had", " a", " little", " lamb" })
            {
                input += s;
                System.Console.WriteLine( Encode(input, key) );
            }
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

which prints

```
3545e064fb59bc4bfc02b6e1c3d4925c898aa504
3249f4c8468d4d67f465937da05b809eaff22fdb
87baaadf5d096677f944015e53d283834eb1e943
6325376820c29a09e3ab30db000033aa71d6927d
54579b0146e2476595381d837ee38863be358213
```

and I get the exact same result for

```
<?php
$secretKey = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';

$signatureString = '';
foreach( array('Marry',' had',' a',' little',' lamb') as $s ) {
    $signatureString .= $s;
    echo hash_hmac('sha1', $signatureString, $secretKey, false), "\n";
}
```

---

edit: [Dmitriy Nemykin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4172723/dmitriy-nemykin) suggested the following edit

```
public static string Encode(string input, byte[] key)
{
    byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input);
    using(var myhmacsha1 = new HMACSHA1(key))
    {
        var hashArray = myhmacsha1.ComputeHash(byteArray);
        return hashArray.Aggregate("", (s, e) => s + String.Format("{0:x2}",e), s => s );
    }
}
```

which was rejected. But as James already pointed out in a comment to this answer at the very least the [using statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) *is* a good point.

Comment: `myhmacsha1.ComputeHash(stream).Aggregate` give an error: that Aggregate isn't define for System.array . Am I missing anything?

Comment: Depends on the .net version you're using, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548651%28v=VS.90%29.aspx

Comment: Is the `MemoryStream` necessary here? Can't your code be shortened to `myhmacsha1.ComputeHash(byteArray)`? Also you should consider wrapping your your `HMACSHA1` with a `using` block (and the `MemoryStream` if it is required).

Comment: VolkerK = hero status

Answer (score 21):

This site has some pretty good examples across languages: http://jokecamp.wordpress.com/2012/10/21/examples-of-creating-base64-hashes-using-hmac-sha256-in-different-languages/

The c# implementation at the time of writing is:

```
private string CreateToken(string message, string secret)
{
 secret = secret ?? "";
 var encoding = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
 byte[] keyByte = encoding.GetBytes(secret);
 byte[] messageBytes = encoding.GetBytes(message);
 using (var hmacsha256 = new HMACSHA256(keyByte))
 {
 byte[] hashmessage = hmacsha256.ComputeHash(messageBytes);
 return Convert.ToBase64String(hashmessage);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.hmacsha1.aspx

quick and dirty code:

```
public string Encode(string input, byte [] key)
{
        HMACSHA1 myhmacsha1 = new HMACSHA1(key);
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes( input );
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream( byteArray ); 
        byte[] hashValue = myhmacsha1.ComputeHash(stream);
        return hashValue.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However your code returns the string `System.Byte[]`.  So I modified the last line to `return BitConverter.ToString(hashValue).Replace("-","").ToLower()` but I am still unable to get this c# code to generate the same hash as the other languages.

Comment: Super late but `string.Join("", Array.ConvertAll(hashValue, b => b.ToString("x2")))` should work.